# How can I use custom svg icons in a lightning component?

Tags: javascript, lightning-aura-components, svg-icon

I have svg icons uploaded as static resource. How can I use these icons in a lightning component?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SFDC svgIcon component
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/resources/lightning-svg-icon-component-helper/

There may be some adaptation if u don't use SLDS svgs but it should do the job :)

Comment: Link is broken. I don't think this method is supported in lightning anymore